# Open e-mail application from ionic 2

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to open the default e-mail client from an ionic 2 app.

I read that using the url scheme 'mailto:' should work. But for some reasons in my application it only works on android but not on iOS.

```
mailto(email) {
  this._platform.ready().then(() => {
      open('mailto:'+email, "_system");
  });
}
```

No errors are raised when the function is called but nothing happens either, whereas if I use an `http` URL the default browser opens as expected on both platforms.

Comment: Are you testing on a real device or in the simulator?

Comment: For iOS I am running in a simulator (10.2) with the lastest ionic version 2.0.4.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do following:

```
mailto(email) {
  this._platform.ready().then(() => {
      window.open('mailto:'+email);
  });
}
```

Comment: I tried window.open and InAppBrowser syntax but it did not work too.

Comment: You mean you are testing this in Browser?

Comment: No I am using the apple iOS simulator for testing, I was referring to this http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/inappbrowser/.

Comment: It won't work on simulator...test it in the real device...it will work like a charm .

Comment: Some testers report that it did not work on their devices, so I think the solution is not working in some cases with ionic 2.0rc5. I put this issue on hold for the moment.

Comment: I am using Ionic 2.0RC.5 and its working fine in Android and iOS. Are you sure you implemented it correctly?

Comment: To give extra-explanations: my problem was caused by the WKWebView plugin.

To make it work, i had to add this line to the config.xml file:
    <access launch-external="yes" origin="*" />
and use in InAppBrowser plugin.

As the answer is good in the general case, I reaccept it.

Answer (score 4):

```
 let Link="mailto:someone@example.com?subject=Hello%20again";
    window.open(Link, "_system");
```

Use this, you don't need a plugin for everything.

Comment: thanks, this is awesome. works on android, have not tested IOS yet

Comment: This works in my case, but it the code is ignored if the user does not have an email client installed. Is there a way to handle a failed attempt to open a default mail client in order for me to alert the user?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Email Composer plugin from Ionic Native

[Link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/email-composer/)

Comment: Unfortunately, I would like to open the e-mail on the default e-mail client of the device. This is not the case with e-mail composer if I understand correctly.

Comment: I am sorry, take a look at the social sharing plugin. More info : https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/social-sharing/

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="ion-home color-primary item" href="#" onclick="window.open('mailto:contact@badhaobusiness.in?subject=I%20have%20a%20query','_system')">contact@badhaobusiness.in</a>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain how this answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users also with similar issues.